# How to save a whole project in python

Tags: python, zodb

Hello I have developed a small game in python using ZODB as backend for DB processing.I have never done game programming before.I was hoping if someone can tell me as to how I can save my current game and then reload it using python.The database filename is data.fs and there are three more ZODB files in my folder.One being for locks rest I'm not aware about.

Comment: You'll have to tell us a bit more about how the game engine works.

Comment: @Mark
It is a simulation game.I'll be simulating a football season.Somewhere in the middle of season,I want to save my state of the game.How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your particular case but maybe ZODB is overkill for this. Check first pickle and also [anydbm](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html#module-anydbm), both at the standard library. If they are not enough for your requirements you can then go for ZODB.

In ZODB, once you are [connected](http://www.zodb.org/zodbbook/installing.html#setting-up-a-connection), you can put anything you want inside as you would with a plain Python dictionary.

You can also use [repoze.zodbconn](http://docs.repoze.org/zodbconn/index.html) to facilitate the configuration, the connection at startup and closing it properly when your program exists.